# Cyclic element in generalized eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Generalized eigenspaces$ H_\lambda$ are a direct sum of cyclic vector spaces $V_1,...,V_n$, which means that there exists an element such that for a given endomorphism $\{v,Av,...,A^{j-1}v\}$ is a basis of such a $V_1,...,V_n$. Now I was wondering how one could find this element for all $V_1,...,V_n$ in a generalized eigenspace?

Comment: I edited my post and hope it is more clear now. ;-)

Comment: It's still not very readable: "for a given endomorphism" is that $A$. That is pretty late to introduce it, given that you already discussed its eigenspaces. The vector $v$ and the exponentn $j$ will need to be different for each $V_i$. And "for all $V_1,\ldots,V_n$" seems to be a misunderstanding; only certain $V_i$ will do.

Comment: I have the feeling that somehow you are going over the proof of the Jordan normal form. But your statements are unclear. Is that it?

Comment: Again: You have an endomorphism $A:V \rightarrow V$. And this will clearly give you some number of generalzed eigenspaces $H_{\lambda}$. Now it is true that each generalzed eigenspace can be written as a direct sum of cyclic vector spaces $V_1,...,V_n$. Now I was wondering: How can I find for each $V_i$ the element that creates this vector space $V_i$, such that $V_i=\text{span}\{v,Av,...,A^{j-1}v\}$?

Comment: Your main problem is that you haven't got the subspaces $V_i$, you just know that they must exist. Given a cyclic vector space, finding a generating vector is easy: just choose anything outside the kernel of $(A-\lambda I)^{d-1}$ where $d$ is the dimension of the cyclic space (this is the largest power for which the kernel does not fill the whole space). My answer treats the harder problem of also finding subspaces $V_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have finished formulating the question correctly, you will no doubt find that you are asking for constructing a decomposition of the generalised eigenspace into Jordan blocks. This decomposition is not unique in general, and a general description of how it can be found can be messy. But after restricting to the generalised eigenspace for one eigenvalue $\lambda$, and subtracting $\lambda I$ from the endomorphism so that what remains is a nilpotent endomorphism$~N$, the following is a possible procedure.

Find the smallest power $k$ such that $N^{k-1}\neq0$, and a vector$~v_1$ that is not killed by$~N^{k-1}$. Choose a linear form $\alpha:V\to\Bbb C$ that does not vanish on $N^{k-1}(v_1)$. Then the space $V_1=\langle v_1,N(v_1),\ldots,N^{k-1}(v_1)\rangle$ can be the first Jordan block, and $C=\{\,v\in V \mid \alpha(v)=0, \ \alpha(N(v))=0, \ \ldots, \ \alpha(N^{k-1}(v))=0\,\}$ is an $N$-stable complement of $V_1$ in$~V$. Now continue with $C$ in place of $V$, using induction on the dimension.